# RxJava Observable behaviour

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am stuck at some I guess easy problem.
When I have api request using retrofit and I am creating Observable in constructor, I do get request do my server every time I subscribe to my observable, but when I have for example `ContentObservable.fromCursor` and it is created exactly the same as above, in a singleton instance, I do not get call to database on every subscribtion, only on first, the same if I do `Observable.just(new Object())`, that object is created only first time it is created, not on every subscribtion, what have I missed?

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: Why does it behave like this, why simple Observable.just does not create new object on every subscribe, just like api call

Comment: If you call "Observable.just(new Object())", the object is created before entering just. If you need lazily create the object, use `defer`: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I have missed